# How to release all artifacts under the target folder?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using the following commands

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

This goal runs fine but only deploys the main jar for the project.

**What have I tried ?**

I tried using the deploy plugin with its deploy-file goal but it is uploading the artifact to jetbrains repository.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy-file -Dfile="target/foo-bar-jar-with-dependencies.jar" -Durl="<my-repo-url>" -Darguments=-DskipTests -DrepositoryId="repo-id"
```

Here is the output

```
Uploading to repo-id: <my-repo-url>/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar
```

> I have hidden some parameters and named within <> for privacy

Here are the artifacts in my target folder

```
src/
target/
   |______ foo-bar.jar <<< this is the main jar
   |______ foo-bar-distribution.zip
   |______ foo-bar-jar-with-dependencies.jar
pom.xml
```

**Question ?**

How do I upload additional artifacts using maven ?

**Update**

By default deploy plugin was picking up some other settings (saw it using -X with maven) so I had to explicitly mention the path to my pom (yes, even though it was in pwd). That seems to work.

Here is what I saw in the debug logs

```
[DEBUG] Using META-INF/maven/org.jetbrains/annotations/pom.xml as pomFile
```

Adding the pomFile attribute with deploy plugin does the trick. Here is the updated command.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy-file -Dfile="target/foo-bar-jar-with-dependencies.jar" -Durl="<my-repo-url>" -Darguments=-DskipTests -DrepositoryId="repo-id" -DpomFile="pom.xml"
```

Here is my build section for the pom

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
                            <includes>
                                <include>${basedir}/target/classes/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly/jar.xml</descriptor>
                        <descriptor>assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.foo.bar.MainKt</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-fat-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-zip</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- this is done to avoid infinite loop of builds -->
                    <scmCommentPrefix>[skip ci]</scmCommentPrefix>
                    <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Please show your pom file....

Comment: If you created the jar/zip with maven-assembly-plugin (and correctly configured it ) you don't need to go via `deploy-file` goal...just use `mvn deploy` wich means use `release:prepare` and `release:perform`...As you wrote it looks/sounds like you have not configure maven-assembly-plugin correctly...but I don't know because you have not posted your pom file..

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you take a look at it now ?